# NetworkX how to access attributes of objects as nodes

Tags: python, networkx

I have created an example graph like this:

```
class myObject(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

one = myObject("ONE")
Graph = nx.Graph()
Graph.add_node(one)
```

**How can I access the attributes of the object "one" in this case?** I figured out that if I add the object as attribute of the node I can access it, however accessing with

```
In [1]: Graph[one]
Out[1]: {}
```

or for example

```
In [2]: print Graph[one]
{}
```

to get the name printed does not work.

I also know that I could iterate over the list returned by

```
Graph.nodes()
```

but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just inspect your object 'one'

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: %paste
class myObject(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

one = myObject("ONE")
Graph = nx.Graph()
Graph.add_node(one)

## -- End pasted text --

In [3]: print(one)
ONE
```

You can store arbitrary data with nodes in NetworkX by using node attributes.  That might be simpler. You could even add a custom object as an attribute.

```
In [4]: G = nx.Graph()

In [5]: G.add_node("ONE", color='red')

In [6]: G.node["ONE"] # dictionary of attributes
Out[6]: {'color': 'red'}

In [7]: G.add_node("ONE",custom_object=one)

In [8]: G.node["ONE"] # dictionary of attributes
Out[8]: {'color': 'red', 'custom_object': <__main__.myObject at 0x988270c>}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. So there is no way of accessing the object by accessing the node other than the ones described, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.  In your case the object *is* the node.